# Is it possible to disable scrolling on all NextJS <Link>s by default?

Tags: reactjs, scroll, next.js

I'm building a site with NextJS and using a fade in and out page transition. I manually scroll the page to the top in between the out and in transitions so the user never sees the jump.

But to do this I am having to set `scroll="false"` on all `<Link>` tags.

I am wondering if there's a way to set scroll to false by default on all Link tags, but I haven't been able to find anything on this subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to make a custom `<Link>` component and use `scroll="false"` on it and import it everywhere you use links.

Comment: Like this. Very simple. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to be helpful!

Comment: Can you provide an example?